# Is defining every variable at the top always the best approach?

Tags: javascript, variables

I've heard that it is a good technique to define your variables at the top of a function, so you don't end up with variable hoisting problems. This:

```
// Beginning of file

function something(){
    var a, b, c = 1, d, e;
    // Do something
}

// End of file
```

is a good example (excluding the bad variable names, of course).

My question is: Is this always the best approach? What if you are working with a lot of variables? Should they really all just be plopped on one line?

Comment: Readers should scroll down to Oleg Pavliv's answer.

Comment: After we got ES6 block scoping, it is preferable to declare a variable where you want to assign it. It really improves maintainability of code by reducing the number of times switching your attention from middle\bottom of the block to the top.

Comment: Chris, I encourage you to un-accept the current answer and allow answers to float based on votes. The advice for this question is going to change a lot over time as JS gains new features.

Comment: JDB: Good point, done.

Answer (score 57):

I'd highly suggest giving [*Code Complete 2* by Steve McConnell](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735619670) a read.  His argument is that you should neither declare all of your variables *in one line*, nor should should declare them all at the top of a routine.  So, don't do this:

```
function foo() {
    var a,
        b,
        c,
        d;

     /**
      * 20 lines that use a and b
      */

     /**
      * 10 lines that use c and d
      */
}
```

Instead, you should declare your variables close to where they are needed.  In the above code, that might look like this:

```
function foo() {
    var a,
        b;

     /**
      * 20 lines that use a and b
      */

     var c,
         d;

     /**
      * 10 lines that use c and d
      */
}
```

The benefits are that you can understand at a quick glance what variables are used by a block of code by just looking at the declarations above it.  You don't need to read the code to see what variables are set, just which are declared.

Don't write code for the compiler or for the computer.  Write it for developers.  Your code should be as easy to read as possible, and require as little effort as possible to understand a particular section of code.

Comment: I've been working my through JavaScript Patterns: http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596806767. That book gave me the idea of putting variable declarations at the top of functions. Say what you want about that advice, but the rest of the book has been excellent.

Comment: This is excellent advice for most modern languages, but I'm seeing advice to the contrary in much of what I read about JavaScript. This is because JavaScript uses functional scoping rather than block scoping. Do you think the scoping issue is relevant?

Comment: I don't think scoping is relevant. The reason is it's not about the compiler block, but the conceptual block. Putting a declaration near usage tells you, the programmer, that the variable is going to be used in this particular context. And as long as you're careful in JS, you can know that you're never using the variable before that point, because you just declared it then. So it gives you a semantic contextual scope to the variable. Rather than just putting it at the top because convention. This is one of the things that C99 got really right...

Comment: I agree. If you have a huge function with many variables being declared and assigned at the top of a scope, where some aren't even used until much later in the routine, it makes it more difficult to read.

Just because all the variables are defined in one place, doesn't make it "organized" or more "readable". It's definitely more understandable to declare variables where they are used. That way, the reader can say "Okay, now this is the code for the Indexing Table parser.". It's neat and tidy, no conglomerations of variable soup with no context.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to split the 2 blocks of code in separate functions where "vars on top" rule would be applied?

Comment: @PetrPeller yes, that is preferable. Small functions with at most one inner block. But that's not always done. So I think the statement still holds value.

Comment: Why in the first place would you have a function with more than 20 statements?? Isn't that a bad coding practise??

Answer (score 30):

### "Should they really all just be plopped on one line?"

**I don't think so.**

Here is how I would write that (ignoring names):

```
function something(){
    var a,
        b,
        c = 1,
        d,
        e;
    // Do something
}
```

This only *looks silly in the above* because 1) the names suck 2) the variables are not assigned in the "declaration" -- most code can be written with immutable (assigned-once) variables and I find this to simplify code. I use this for multiple reasons including clarity and *resistance to formatting changes* (that is, I can change the initial values, add/or remove declarations, etc, without mucking about the formatting of the other lines).

### "Is defining every variable at the top always the best approach?"

**I don't think so.**

For instance, here is how I write loops:

```
for (var i = 0; i < x; i++) {
  var elm = elms[i];
  ...
}
```

And some people will go "BUT THE VAR IS HOISTED TO THE TOP OF THE FUNCTION!" or "A VARIABLE IS FUNCTION-SCOPED!". Well, indeed. However, that allows me to easily *visually* see that this is an error, even if the JavaScript engine won't help:

```
for (var i = 0; i < x; i++) {
  var elm = elms[i];
  ...
}
...
// valid JS but since I consider this construct *invalid*
// I know this is a *bug* in my code
alert(elm);
```

As far as when I assign to variables caught in closures: it depends. If the variable is used in only a single closure I generally put it right above. This lets me know it *should only be used in that closure*. If the variable is shared (e.g. `self`) I put it above all the applicable closures -- generally in the "variable declaration section" of the function. This lets me know it has a "function-wide scope" (read: likely to be used in multiple bindings).

To address the "for-each closure issue" -- just learn the language. Keeping variable "declarations" close to the closure does not affect this in anyway. If the construct is not understood, it really doesn't matter *how* the code is written.

I use these approaches to/because:

1. Have consistent easy-to-scan code.
2. Write code that *tells me when it's wrong*.
3. I prefer code that is amendable to altering without changing structure.
4. Self-documenting code means less comments.
5. I like to "read vertically"

Happy coding.

Comment: If you have two for loops, one after another, it's tempting to re-use the `var elem`. Except that the `elem` carries it's value from one for-loop to the next which can cause some very unexpected behavior, depending on your logic. This is extremely confusing code, especially for new devs who may not be used to JS or who do not know the code.

Answer (score 15):

In languages with block scope, it is usually recommended that variables be declared at the site of first use.

But because JavaScript does not have block scope, it is wiser to declare all of a function's variables at the top of the function. This way you don't fool yourself or other people about the variable's scope.

EDIT: Many people work with several languages simultaneously. Often JavaScript is the only one among them without the block scope.

Comment: Anyone who thinks javascript has block scope shouldn't be touching javascript code.

Comment: I agree with Raynos. While this is *technically true*, putting all the variables at the top of the function *reduces* the ability of the code to self-document.

Comment: JavaScript has block script now with the [`let` keyword](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-let-and-const-declarations). Note that this feature is not recommended if you need [backwards compatibility](http://caniuse.com/#feat=let).

Comment: Putting declarations at the top of the function tends to end in a big ugly mess for me once the function grows large enough and I have to modify it, say, to separate a block out into its own function. How do I know which variables belong to that block? I go up to the top of the function, now I see a mess of variable declarations and have to figure out which ones I need to transplant. It's unmaintable. I've only been doing it because of jslint/jshint. I'm reconsidering based on this question.

Comment: The lack of block scope is an important thing to know and keep in mind, however, defining variables nearest their first use keeps the code cleaner and easier to follow.  It's still worthwhile for that reason.  Generally, if you're writing in a language you should know the scoping rules in any case.

Answer (score 9):

This is a style question. Not a functionality question.

The javascript parser will take this code

```
function() {
   dostuff();
   var i = 4;
}
```

and turn it into :

```
function() {
   var i;
   dostuff();
   i = 4;
}
```

As for the style question. No thank you I thought we left that behind with ANSI C.

What you want to do is declare functions at the top of their "scope"

If the "scope" of a variable is the entire function then declare them at the top. If the "scope" is a subset of a function then declare them at the start of the subset.

treat "scope" as logical scope rather then function scope.

This should ensure maximum readability.

Comment: But the behavior of "hoisting" the variables to the top of the function can change the functionality of the code, if you weren't expecting it. Defining every variable at the top of the function is designed to help you to not run into those issues.

Comment: @SimpleCoder in terms of readability declare the variables at the highest point of their scope. You do know javascript only has function scope right?

Answer (score 4):

I would venture to say that in older structures (such as the C\C++ days) it was important to initialize your variables and assign them a start value. But with the way things have been going, I'm finding that declaring them "when necessary" is a valid implementation. Unless scope is playing a part (for instance you need variable `a` not only in that function, but also in other functions, too), I would declare on-the-go.

Maybe it's just way of thinking, but I tend to declare things based on scope (If the variable is needed only within an if condition or a few lines of code, I'll declare it there (rather than at the top of my function/class). If I don't go through that code path, I think of it as saving the memory allocation and it won't be declared for "no reason".)

I could be completely wrong, however. Either way, JavaScript will allow you to declare your variables in any fashion you deem easiest to read.

Comment: Any variable declaration is hoisted to the top of the nearest function declaration so declaring in an if statement does not save memory. I do think you should stick to declaring a variable at the top of it's "logical scope".

Comment: @Raynos: Yea, I tend to dislike "cluttered" declarations all over my function. Moreover though, I'm lazy and find that little extra scrolling to the top when I need a new variable is too much. And I'm obviously wrong about saving memory, but sure saves some arrow key presses/shift to the mouse for scroll. ;p

Comment: and makes the code more readable in terms of logical scope of a variable.

Answer (score 4):

This is really just a matter of preference. For example, if my method only contains a for loop, then I won't extract the loop variables to the top:

```
var func = function(arr) {
    for (var i = 0, len = arr.length; i < len; i++) {
        // array processing here
    }
}
```

Almost all other times though I will place ALL variables at the top for hoisting reasons. If you find that there are too many variables at the top of your function, it could be an indication that your method is doing too much work, and should consider extracting a portion of it into some sort of helper method. This will let you organize your variables based on functionality.

Comment: When you say "for hoisting reasons", the goal is to indicate clearly that the scope of the variable is the whole function?  Are there other reasons also?

Comment: @JonOnstott: As I understand it, there is no other reason to declare vars at the top of its scope other than to avoid bugs (the type which should not occur anyway), satisfying your linter, and annoying your co-workers.

Comment: If your method contains only loop logic then you can use ```arr.forEach(func);```