# The benefits of declaring variables at the top of the function body in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I am reading Douglas Crockford's book ["Javascript: The Good Parts"](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596517742). He is talking about scope and saying that JS doesn't have block scope:

> In many modern languages, it is recommended that variables be declared
>   as late as possible, at the first point of use. That turns out to be
>   bad advice for Javascript because it lacks block scope. So instead, it
>   is best to declare all of the variables used in a function at the top
>   of the function body.

However, I couldn't think of a good example why this statement makes sense and it would be really nice to see some examples which verify this statement.

Comment: Think of `for` loops in the same scope, using the same `i` variable. Declaring `i` first and reuse it seems more correct or idiomatic.

Comment: If you declare it with var, it will be local in scope. If not it will be global. So to make it clear that the var is local, declare it explicitly in the beginning of the function

Comment: Declare variables at the top of the function as a means of documenting all variables used in one place. It also avoids confusion resulting from someone imagining that a variable is block-scoped when it is in fact not.

Comment: @mplungjan The question as I understand it is not about whether or not to declare variables, but rather where in the function to declare them.

Comment: @elclanrs: I don't think that it is the main reason of why Douglas recommended it.

Comment: @mplungjan: `var` is completely separate topic than what I am asking for.

Comment: it just avoids the confusion that is usually associated with the scope behavior of javascript, especially for people coming from other programming languages. By declaring on top of the function you are making sure the structure of your code is inline with the actual behavior of the runtime(which is no matter where u declare the variable, i will pull them all to the top and yeah only just the declaration).

Comment: @Tarik You're asking about variable declarations and `var` **is** how variables are declared, so how is it a completely separate topic?

Comment: @torazaburo: I am talking about the location of the variable, not whether you should use `var` or not. Of course one should use `var`but it is not what I am asking for. I am asking for why the location matters whereas he/she is talking about the benefits of `var`.

Comment: Variables in JS are always declared before anything can happen. This is done for you by the runtime compiler.

Comment: Personally, I would reduce as much trouble for the compiler as I can. Javascript `hoists` variable declarations anyway, so even if you declare them anywhwere, compliler will move them at the top of their context. Why not save compiler some time by not making the compiler get engaged in things that you can do as good practive?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Declaring variables at the top helps you avoid situations like this:

```
function outer() {
  var i = 50;

  function inner() {
    alert(i);
    var i= 30;
  }
  inner();
}

outer();
```

Many people would expect the alert to show `50`, and they would be surprised to see `undefined`.  That's because the `i` variable is declared within the `inner` function, but it isn't initialized until after the `alert`.  So it has full function scope, even though it's declared after its initial use.

Comment: It's a simplistic example, but `i` is a common loop variable.  A C programmer might see `for(var i = ...)` and mistakenly think `i` has block scope.  Declaring variables at top may help legibility and maintainability, but I have to admit that I rarely declare loop variables before use.

Comment: Just to clarify, this is due to hoisting so the function inner is actually `var i; alert(i); i = 30;`

Comment: Correct.  The term "hoisting" didn't come to mind until after I saw @torazaburo's post.

Comment: That's only because you used `var i = 30;`. Take off the `var` and you get `50`. When you use the keyword `var` within a function it scopes that `var` to that function.

Comment: @Assaf: Your clarification was really nice. Thanks for that!

Answer (score 3):

Declare variables at the top of the function as a means of documenting all variables used in one place.

It also avoids confusion resulting from someone imagining that a variable is block-scoped when it is in fact not, as in the following:

```
var i=0;
if (true) {
   var i=1;
}
// what is i? C programmer might imagine it's 0.
```

If variables are also being initialized at declaration time, putting the declarations at the top avoids potential problems with the timing of the initialization:

```
console.log(foo);
var foo = 1;
```

In this case, `foo` is hoisted so it is declared at the time of the `console.log`, but has not yet been initialized. So this is effectively like

```
var foo;
console.log(foo); // no ReferenceError, but undefined
foo = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

From my point of view, as javascript do not have block scope, declaring all variables on top of the function makes you spot easier variables you do not have to use as you can reuse an other.

Example :

```
function test(){
    var pages = [
        'www.stackoverflow.com',
        'www.google.com'
    ];

    var users = [
        'John',
        'Bob'
    ];

    for (var page = 0; page < pages.length; page++) {
        console.log(pages[page]);
    };

    for (var user = 0; user < users.length; user++) {
        console.log(users[user]);
    };
}
```

Can be changed to :

```
function test(){
    var index, pages, users;

    pages = [
        'www.stackoverflow.com',
        'www.google.com'
    ];

    users = [
        'John',
        'Bob'
    ];

    for (index = 0; index < pages.length; index++) {
        console.log(pages[index]);
    };

    for (index = 0; index < users.length; index++) {
        console.log(users[index]);
    };
}
```

And save one variable space from the memory.

In such a small function the main point may not be visible, but imagine a whole project with thousand lines of code. This may make your code run faster.

Comment: Shouldn't you now remove the `var` from your `for` loops?

Comment: It may be somewhat related but still I don't think that it is the reason of why Douglas recommends it. If this is the case then we should do it all the time even in modern languages.

Comment: Some ideas here too http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5053073/is-defining-every-variable-at-the-top-always-the-best-approach

Comment: Use `var` in loops. You can have problems if your loop is in a function now your increment is global. You might not be thinking about in and accidentally redefine a variable at a higher level scope.

Answer (score 0):

That's not always a good idea. It depends what you're doing. What they mean when they say it's not necessary to declare `"top level"` variables, is that it doesn't matter. It can matter inside a function. Consider the following examples:

```
varOne = 1; varTwo = 2; varThree = 3; // undeclared
function lameFunc(){
  var varOne = 'Something'; // does no affect varOne at the top level
  return varOne;
}
```

Same as:

```
var varOne = 1, varTwo = 2, varThree = 3; // declared
function lameFunc(){
  var varOne = 'Something'; // does no affect varOne at the top level
  return varOne;
}
```

Of course, it's easier to see the variables with the keyword `var` and since there are no adverse effects at the `"top level"`, it is recommended.

Notice that, when I change `lameFunc()` you affect the higher lever `var`, either way.

```
function lameFunc(){
  /* varOne is effected at the higher level whether or not `var` is declared
    above as in `varOne = 1` or `var varOne = 1` */
  varOne = 'Something';
  return varOne;
}
```

Additionally, if you declare a variable outside of event like `var someInputVal = document.getElementById('someInput').value;`, then lets say you want to get the value onclick of an Element. You would want the `var` declared within the `Element.onclick = function(){/* in here */}` because the input may have changed before you clicked on `Element`. It may be okay to declare `var someInput = document.getElementById('someInput');` outside of the function that handles your Event, if the Element doesn't become `undefined` then you can access the like:

```
var doc = document, bod = doc.body;
function E(e){
  return doc.getElementById(e);
}
var someInput = E('someInput'), someInputVal = someInput.value;
E('clickButton').onclick = function(){
  console.log(someInputVal); // will not be what document.getElementById('someInput').value is if it was changed before clicking
  var declared = someInput.value;
  console.log(declared);
}
```