# variable difference between function scope javascript

Tags: javascript, variables, scope

I am reading the topics about the execution context and scope of javascript.Below is a simple code:

```
 var scope="global";  
    function t(){  
        alert(scope);  // alert :"undefined"
        var scope="local" ; 
        alert(scope);  // alert: "local"
    }  
    t();
```

If I remove '**var scope="local" ;** ' ,it becomes this:

```
var scope="global";  
function t(){  
    alert(scope);  // alert :"global"   
}  
t();
```

I don't understand why the value of scope is changed to "global" in the second case after I remove **var scope="local"** in the function t().

Could someone help to explain this, thank you!

Comment: Do you understand why the fist `alert` shows `undefined` in the first example?

Comment: @DiegoCardoso I actually don't understand. Mind posting a link to an example please?

Comment: @RobScott It's because of hoisting. Any variable defined within a function is hoisted to the top of that function. So, in this case, he's redefining the same variable, but at the first line, `scope` isn't initialized yet. You can take a look at the link in the @Tim's answer.

Comment: @Steven Liang can you accept an answer please?

Answer (score 3):

When you do this:

```
scope = 'global'
function t() {
  alert(scope) // undefined
  var scope = 'func'
  alert(scope) // func
}
t()
```

at the line `var scope...`, you're telling js: **watch out, I'm defining 'scope' in this function**. So JS resets it's value (undefined). It's like if you did:

```
scope = 'global'
function t() {
  var scope; // erase previous 'scope', so it is now undefined
  alert(scope) // undefined
  scope = 'func'
  alert(scope) // func
}
t()
```

But if you just do

```
scope = 'global'
function t() {
  alert(scope) // global
}
t()
```

You're not creating the variable `scope` in your function, so JS does not erase it's value, and when you try to access it, JS tries to find it higher (in the global namespace in this case)

Hope you get it... It indeed a bit weird, because first, JS looks for every variable you are declaring in you function (and reset/initialise them) and *then* run your function.

Matt

Answer (score 2):

Essentially, in your first example, the scope of `scope` (i.e. the var declared inside the function) is the entire body of the function `t`. It doesn't have a value until it gets to the `var scope == ...` line, but it is defined from the beginning.

So `alert(scope)` is resolve "scope" as the locally defined variable, that does not yet have a value - that is, it's `undefined`.

See this question

[The benefits of declaring variables at the top of the function body in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25945467/the-benefits-of-declaring-variables-at-the-top-of-the-function-body-in-javascrip)

for more explanation.

Answer (score 0):

```
var scope="global";  
function t(){ 
    // you redefine variable scope here
    // so, the global one is not visible.

    alert(scope);  // alert :"undefined"
    alert(window.scope); //alert: "global"
    var scope="local" ; 
    alert(scope);  // alert: "local"
}  
t();
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because of a concept called hoisting in javascript. The variable scope in function t() gets hoisted to the beginning of the function I.e it gets initialized with undefined and later 'local' is assigned to it.